# Turn on a Linux machine remotely

Tags: networking, ssh, ubuntu-9.04

My previous laptop is in really poor physical condition, so my plan is to leave it at home as a scraping server (accessed by ssh). How would I remotely turn it off/on? (or do anything else like sleep/hibernate)

Answer (score 6):

Use "Wake-on-LAN" (WOL) **IF** you have a device in front of it that supports it (e.g. a Linksys WRT54GL with [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or DD-WRT). Keep in mind that your laptop also has to support this from the BIOS! If not: use a clock-timer to turn it on might be a work-around...

I used it like this on such a device: [Wake-on-LAN (tutorial)](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WOL).
Again: if you don't have such a device I would use a clock-timer. ;-)

You can turn the system off through SSH and as root do

```
shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 3):

Shutdown part: this is easy as you can shutdown the machine by issuing a

```
shutdown -h now
```

in SSH. You have to launch this as root but giving root SSH access is *really really bad* practice. You should disable the root access and use sudo or su to launch the command.

---

Wake up part: you didn't mention if this server should be turned on only by machines in the LAN or if you want to turn it on from the Internet; in the first case it's simple, in the second you'll have troubles if your router doesn't support static routes.
WOL is absolutely not supported by WiFi network cards.

- WOL (Wake on LAN)

  - Enter the BIOS of your server machine and enable the wake on lan/wake on network feature. Normally laptop BIOSes have no settings other than on/off for this feature.
  - Boot your Ubuntu and run "*sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g*" assuming eth0 is your network card. This command is for being sure that your network card will turn on your machine only on [magic packets](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_Packet).
  - run also "*sudo ifconfig*" and annotate the MAC address of the network card as it is required later to wake the PC.
  - Shutdown the server machine as it is ready to be woken up.
  - Find a program on your client machine (the one that wakes up the server) that is able to forge the famous magic packet and install it. "wakeonlan" is a good choice as it is right also for the WOW.
  - Learn how to use it: normally you're asked for the server MAC address and *nothing else* as in LAN the frame will be broadcasted.
- Wake on WAN (WOW)

  - Do all the steps on the WOL.
  - Check in the web interface of your router if you can assign a MAC Address to a static IP (static routes). If your router doesn't support it (most of the domestic routers I have seen don't) you can't wake your server from the Internet.
  - If you're lucky and have static routes: assign the server mac address to a static IP. Then go to the server and set that IP the way you prefer (via console or gui, indifferent).
  - "Open a port" on the router, telling it that a UDP port (you choose the number) will be redirected to the local server IP.
  - Now with the above program and your external IP address you should be able to wake up your server really remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the `sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g`! For some reason it seems wol was disabled by default and it didn't work until I ran this command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wake-on-LAN.

> Wake-on-LAN enables users to turn on a
>   computer across a network from another
>   network device. It can be very useful
>   in situations where computers are not
>   all next to each other or there are a
>   lot of machines. WoL works by sending
>   a packet of data called a Magic
>   Packet™ to the target machine. When
>   the packet is received, the target
>   machine's network device (Network
>   Interface Controller or NIC) wakes-up
>   the rest of the machine.

[**Ubuntu** does support it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan).